# how to create or save contact in dual sim in android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, sim-card

```
 private fun addContactToSim(number: String, name: String) {
        try {

            val simUri = Uri.parse("content://icc/adn")
            val cv = ContentValues()
            cv.put("tag", name)
            cv.put("number", number)
            cv.put("email", "Email")
            context.getContentResolver().insert(simUri, cv)
            context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(simUri, null)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

this code tried to save or create contact to sim but i want save contact based on option like if we select sim 1 it should save in sim1 if we select sim 2 it should save sim 2 can any one suggest me how to get this plz help i am stucking from long time in this issue.